# Множественный выбор в SlickGrid без зажатия клавиш-модификаторов

Tags: javascript, html, grid

Есть необходимость реализовать множественный выбор в SlickGrid без использования <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> и <kbd>Shift</kbd>. На англоязычном SO [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27606231/2572082) использовать собственную реализацию RowSelectionModel, но почему-то не объясняют, как это сделать.

Можно получить более подробную инструкцию о том, как реализовать свою RowSelectionModel?